# Python, tuple index out of range + sql syntax error

Tags: python, mysql, python-2.7

I have problem with my database (MySQLdb) while using Python (Python-2.7). I have table with 3 columns, id, message1, message2. For example

1. Hello :)  Hi
2. How are you? Fine

I want my program to search column message1 to find "Hi" and if that message doesn't exist, search column message2 to find it and if it exist send "Hello :)" If message doesnt exist in both columns I am sending random message. But it is not as obvious that I thought. Here is my code

```
if is_send==0:
    try:
        cursor.execute("""SELECT message1 FROM Messages WHERE message2 LIKE (%s) limit 1""",('%' +text+'%',))
        data=cursor.fetchall()
        time.sleep(3)
        send(data)
        is_send=1
        print data
        print" - sent message 2"
    except Exception as sending_message:
        print sending_message
if is_send==0:
    try:
        cursor.execute("""SELECT message2 FROM messages WHERE message1 LIKE (%s) limit 1""",('%' +text+'%',))
        data=cursor.fetchall()
        time.sleep(3)
        send(data)
        is_send=1
        print data
        print " - sent message 3"
    except Exception as sending_message:
        print sending_message
    if is_send==0:
        cursor.execute("""SELECT tresc FROM Wiadomosci.tabwiadprzych ORDER BY rand() limit 1""")
        data=cursor.fetchall()
        time.sleep(3)
        send(data)
        print data
        print " - sent message 4"
```

I get tuple index out of range when I'm trying to search column message1 and what's more "1064, "You have an error in your SQL syntax;" 
In SELECT I was trying to write

```
("""SELECT message1 FROM messages WHERE message2 LIKE (%s) limit 1""", [text])
```

Or

```
("""SELECT message1 FROM messages WHERE message2 LIKE (%s) limit 1""", text)
```

or

```
("""SELECT message1 FROM messages WHERE message2 LIKE (%%s%%) limit 1""", [text])
```

or even

```
query=("SELECT message1 FROM messages WHERE message2 LIKE (%s) limit 1")
cursor.execute(query,(tekst,))
```

And it won't work. I have no idea what can I do in this situation. Maybe there is something wrong with try:

Sending random message (message 4) is working but program always tries to send message 2 and doesn't even check second or third if

Comment: Did you first execute your query in the database server and make sure that you get results there?

Comment: If it is, it would be more safer to do the following when you insert variables to strings: "SELECT message1 FROM Messages WHERE message2 LIKE %{}% limit 1".format(text)

Comment: I highly recommend for you to first run the query in the server, make sure it returns results as desired, then copy paste the exact query, and replace the input with a {} and then pass whatever the variable as a parameter to format. You can find the bug for your sql query by running the query in the server itself. Once you solve that part, could check and see what's going wrong with the rest.

Comment: Sure, I have different file when I test the query in Python. They are working and return me everything that I expect, after that I paste them to my program and it doesn't work. No idea why. I will check your advise with that SELECT

Comment: Yes please. And let us know how that goes.

Comment: I had similar one error and it turns out that your values must be tuples or in this case (text, ). For example `'SELECT * FROM %s' % (text, )`

Comment: @picmate I was trying to use your solution but id didn't work I get similar error

Comment: I was trying to use your solution but id didn't work I get similar error

(1064, "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '%Hello% limit 1' at line 1")

@Boris I'm not sure if I understood how my query should look like, something like this?

cursor.execute("SELECT message1 FROM messages WHERE message2 LIKE %s " %(text,))

then I get (1054, "Unknown column 'Hello' in 'where clause'")
(hello is messate (text) Why it thinks that hello is a column?

I think I am stupid xd

Comment: Could you print the sql query that you form in side the script, and try running it in mysql? For example, before cursor.execute(query), do a print(query)

Comment: Since you said the query didn't give you an error when you run in mysql, it should be when you form it inside your script. The error you get is from mysql, not python.

Comment: Actually, I did a print of your sql query, this is what I get: 'SELECT message2 FROM messages WHERE message1 LIKE (%s) limit 1', ('%BOBO%',); this will most certainly throw an error

Comment: However, when I do the following, I could form a correct sql statement: "SELECT message2 FROM messages WHERE message1 LIKE '%{0}%' limit 1".format(text)

Comment: A print yields: "SELECT message2 FROM messages WHERE message1 LIKE '%BOBO%' limit 1"

Comment: My code works and I have no idea why.jpg  Anyway that was a problem with my program not with sql becouse I copied content from function send() instead using it and message about syntax disappeared + send(data) <- this is wrong and should be like this: send(data[0]) Thanks for your time and have a nice day. That was good lesson :)